# Display an HTML form via Javascript document.write?

Tags: javascript, document.write

If I am way off on how to employ this code then please forgive me, but is it possible to use something like

```
var url = 'http://www.maxcashtitleloans.com/lmapp.html'
document.write('<script src="'+url+'"></scr'+'ipt>')
```

to somehow display an html form inside many websites across different servers?

I have a single HTML form that will be continually updated as the needs of the company change, and would like to get them off of IFRAME calls.

A different questions towards the same goal "How can I display off site content on a website and not use IFRAME"

I know of an affiliate marketing company that uses

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    var inputOptions = { 
        UserID: '35696', 
        Product: 'payday', 
        ProductTemplate: 'lights', 
        Server: 'https://altohost.com/', 
        mobileDevices: true, 
        parseDefaultValue: true, 
        visitor: { 
            referrer: (document.cookie.match("rfrrr[\r\n\t ]*=[\r\n\t ]*(.*?)(;|$)") || [,''])[1],   
            subaccount: (document.cookie.match("src[\r\n\t ]*=[\r\n\t ]*(.*?)(;|$)") || [,''])[1], 
            keyword: (document.cookie.match("kwrd[\r\n\t ]*=[\r\n\t ]*(.*?)(;|$)") || [,''])[1], 
            clickid: (document.cookie.match("clcid[\r\n\t ]*=[\r\n\t ]*(.*?)(;|$)") || [,''])[1] 
        },     
    }; 
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://altohost.com/system/applicationforms/init.php?vn=inputOptions"></scr'+'ipt>'); 
</script>
```

Comment: May be better to use PHP.

Comment: Do you control all the servers?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl and how PHP supposed to address that?

Comment: I control all servers, yes. I dont want google to see me connecting 900 websites. I know of a affiliate marketer that uses this code to accomplish what Im trying to do.

Comment: You could do it server-side instead of trying to get the client to do it. You didn't mention what you're using for the web server.

Comment: Then you may want to use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to allow cross-domain requests, then use ajax to fetch the forms.

Comment: You may not want to follow the altohost method as they appear to be some sort of spamming operation according to http://blog.sucuri.net/tag/malware - please perform your own checks to see if that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there is solution for you. Your embed code like this;

```
<script>
var url = 'http://www.maxcashtitleloans.com/lmapp.js'
document.write('<script src="'+url+'"></scr'+'ipt>')
</script>
```

And http://www.maxcashtitleloans.com/lmapp.js like this :

```
function ajaxex()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","lmapp.htm",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
ajaxex();
```

Thats work fine. And demo for you : http://commention.com/lmappjsexample/
That solution like javascript proxy, you have to create a javascript file for render your html page.

Answer (score 2):

I'd propose a slightly different approach.

Use JavaScript to create the HTML form and include that script into all other websites using the same source.

Assume `form.js` is the file you want to include in every website.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/AY9mr/)

**forms.js**

```
var company = {};// Avoid name clashes!!!

company.form = function() {
    this.render();
};

company.form.prototype.render = function() {
    var url = "blablabla";
    this.form = document.createElement("form");
    this.form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    this.form.setAttribute("name", "company-specialform");
    this.form.setAttribute("action", url);

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input.setAttribute("value", "test");

    var submit = document.createElement("input");
    submit.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    submit.setAttribute("value", "submit");
    this.form.appendChild(input);
    this.form.appendChild(submit);
    var that = this;
    this.form.onsubmit = function(event) {
        that.submit.call(that, event);
    };
};

company.form.prototype.submit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // if needed
    alert(" Custom submit was called");
};

company.form.prototype.getForm = function() {
    return this.form;
};

company.form.append = function(container) {
    var form = new company.form();
    container.appendChild(form.getForm());
};

var target = document.getElementById("container");

company.form.append(target);
```

Now simply include `forms.js` on any other website, but make sure you use the same `src` for all of those websites, so you can keep the script up to date.

Now on every of those website, they can add the form with `company.form.append(someDiv)` and when you update the script the update will be available on all websites.

Comment: The form is an HTML form, not a javascript form. Will this still work?

Comment: This will not work for the OP. The OP is trying to include an HTML page with a form on it.

Comment: I suppose, but if the OP doesn't know JS or HTML all that well, which I assume as he's trying to load HTML via a script tag, then that may not be the best way for him to go.

Comment: Wait why would you do this... this javascript is adding an iframe, that what he was trying to avoid in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple jQuery:

```
<script>
$('body').load(url);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, a `<script>` tag is for including javascript, not HTML. You want to look into [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You want to load the html file via ajax into a div.

Alternatively, leave it as an iframe. Iframes are for including one page into another.

**Edit**
The example you included from the affiliate is meaningless for you. They are loading javascript that is generated programmatically from a PHP server side script based on input from client side cookies. You are trying to load en external html file, these are two different tasks.

**javascript in your HEAD tag**

```
<!-- Include the jquery library - never re-create the wheal -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Run once the page is loaded
    $('#putFormHere').load('http://www.maxcashtitleloans.com/lmapp.html');
});
</script>
```

**Replace your current iframe with this**

```
<div id='putFormHere'></div>
```

**Assumption**

I'm assuming that `www.maxcashtitleloans.com` is the same domain as your current page. If not then they *only* way to do this is via an iframe. Javascript will not support cross-site scripting.

Comment: Will doing this allow view source to see the coding of the html form? Or will it hide it like the method in my first question does?

Comment: The Ajax method that is, not the IFRAME method.

Comment: Depends on the browser, some will let you inspect javascript create DOM elements, some will not. If you are trying to hide the included HTML from the user there is *no* way to do this.

Comment: Meaningless? I want to accomplish the same thing as them, have a form display on a website and not show the code that creates the form.

Comment: @user1789437 You cannot hide the code from someone who really wants to see it. The code has to get to the browser: it can be intercepted on the way. What makes it so secret?

Answer (score -2):

Script tags do not HTML rendering. You have to add HTML render to your html page. Maybe you can add this code to your html page. This code render your html codes on javascript.

```
document.write($(body).html());
```

Comment: Oh? Any help on how to call this?

Comment: document write body is not working because your code is so complex. alternative way you can use ajax load with cross domain xml.